# How to get clicked button that was created dynamically?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a dynamically created button in order to access its parent.
I already tried to do:

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");   
btn.innerHTML="Add";  
addButton.appendChild(btn);
btn.addEventListener("click(this)", add);
```

sadly the button won't work if i type `"click(this)"`. It only works if  I type `"click"`.

Changing the method to `function add(element)` from `function add()` also did not work.

How can i access the parent of my clicked button?
I cant create my buttons in HTML since i am creating a dynamic list of buttons which may differ depending on the size of the array.
Also my code should only be in Javascript

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Because `click(this)` is not a native event name. And what is `add`? It's nowhere to be found in your code. Moreover, it _appears_ that you're appending a button to another button element: you aren't suppose to nest clickable elements inside another.

Comment: What I'm understanding of your question is that you want to access this button parent and in this case you can use`.parentNode` for example `var parent = btn.parentNode;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By magic, I mean by the standard, the button reference is passed to the object.

```js
function add() {
  console.log(this);
}


var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");   
btn.innerHTML="Add";  
addButton.appendChild(btn);
btn.addEventListener("click", add);
```

```html
<div id="addButton"></div>
```

If you really wanted to pass along a variable

```js
function add(btn, what) {
  console.log(btn, what);
}


var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");   
btn.innerHTML="Add";  
addButton.appendChild(btn);
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){ add(this,'foo'); });
```

```html
<div id="addButton"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp
You should use `btn.addEventListener("click", () => {})` instead of `btn.addEventListener("click", () => {})`.

But I think it would be better to use `document.addEventListener((e) => {})` and then check the target (`e.target`)